# How do I get news feeds? Just like News and Weather app

Tags: android, fetch, feed

I'm trying to know how to implement the news feed retrieval, just like how it is on the News and Weather app:

In the app (News and Weather), you have the option of writing the name, then the app retrieves the news based upon it. (Menu -> Settings -> News Settings -> Select news topics)

For example, if I say "Android", it'll fetch me news relating to "Android".

Is this based on RSS? How does it work and how can I implement it in my app?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am saying as i understand:
u want to make news search box* : user type any word and find latest news about written topic:
i think u have to store ur RSS feed in db and then fire query on db and display news...

Comment: You understood me right! But I'm not entirely sure if your method is correct. That means the user will type a "name" then gets a feed on whatever matches in the db. I don't think storing RSS feeds in a db is the real answer to such issue.

Comment: ok, can u please explain which type of feed u have i mean u search with feed or ur feed provide news and u want filter..

Comment: I've given it more thought and I now I think the db approach (Or in other words, storing them) might be the right answer after all! I believe the official news app on android actually does take the entered "name" and searches through pre-defined feeds. I kinda noticed this now after using it.

Thanks a lot! :)